# Why can ansible not connect to MySql?

Tags: mysql, ansible, debian

I want to deploy a MySql database server with these configurations.

This is my playbook to deploy MySql :

```yaml
- name: "Inclure le fichier : install_utilitaires_mysql.yaml"
  include: install_utilitaires_mysql.yaml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Telechargement d'un package .deb pour ajouter le repo mysql"
  get_url:
    url: https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
    dest: /tmp
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Installation du package .deb"
  apt:
    deb: /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Mise a jour des sources list : apt update"
  apt:
   update_cache: yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Installation de MySql"
  apt:
    name: mysql-server
    state: latest
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Demarrer le service MySql"
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: started
    enabled: yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Voir la variable mysql_username"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ mysql_username }}"
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Création du user : {{ mysql_username }}"
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ mysql_username }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_password }}"
    priv: '*.*:ALL'
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

But when I execute this playbook with the `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml --vault-password-file password` command, I will get this error :

```sh
TASK [Création du user : {{ mysql_username }}] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.1.41]
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password
fatal: [192.168.1.37]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, u\"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

Why can ansible not connect to MySQL while `mysql -u root` works perfectly fine?

I found this solution but I don't understand how it works:

```yaml
- name: Example using login_unix_socket to connect to server
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: root
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

## First food for thought

I found this code

```yaml
---
- name: "Inclure le fichier : install_utilitaires_mysql.yaml"
  include: install_utilitaires_mysql.yaml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Telechargement d'un package .deb pour ajouter le repo mysql"
  get_url:
    url: https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
    dest: /tmp
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Installation du package .deb"
  apt:
    deb: /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Mise a jour des sources list : apt update"
  apt:
   update_cache: yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Installation de MySql"
  apt:
    name: mysql-server
    state: latest
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Demarrer le service MySql"
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: started
    enabled: yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  
- name: "Envoi du template .my.cnf dans ~"
  template:
    src: root_cnf.j2
    dest: ~/.my.cnf
    owner: root
    mode: 0600
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Redemarrer le service MySql"
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: restarted
    enabled: yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: "Création du user : {{ mysql_username }}"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: root
    name: "{{ mysql_username }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_password }}"
    priv: '*.*:ALL'
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

But when I executed this `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml --vault-password-file password` command I get this error:

```sh
TASK [Création du user : {{ mysql_username }}] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.43.102]
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password
fatal: [192.168.43.182]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /********/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, u\"Access denied for user '********'@'localhost'\")"}
```

**Question** : Why does running my playbook result in this error?

Knowing that the `root_cnf.j2` jinja2 file contains this configuration :

```
[client]
user=root
password=root
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you wrote, you need to use `login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (replace the path to the socket if necessary) as the password-less login is only available using the socket, not using the network.

See [this post on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274547/cant-set-root-password-after-fresh-installation-of-mariadb-using-ansible).

It is basically a security feature, so you do not accidentally expose a password-less access to a database on the internet.

What you want to do is first

```yaml
- name: Set password for root user
  mysql_user:
    name: "root"
    password: "{{ mysql_password }}"
    priv: '*.*:ALL,GRANT'
    host: 'localhost'
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    state: present
```

which will set a password for `root`. After that the login for `root` via the network will be enabled.
Afterwards, you want to do something like this:

```yaml
- name: Save root password in .my.cnf
  template:
    src: root_cnf.j2
    dest: /root/.my.cnf
    owner: root
    mode: '0600'
```

With the template being this:

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ mysql_root_password }}
```

This will put your password in `/root/.my.cnf` so you are able to just use `mysql` on the machine without providing credentials (ansible will pick that up).

Then you can add users with this:

```yaml
- name: "Create mysql user {{ mysql_username }}"
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ mysql_username }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_password }}"
    priv: '*.*:ALL'
```

which is what you want, I guess.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Toydarian :)

But, can I deploy MySql and define the username and a password with Ansible ?

Because it's very simple to do it and not use the socket. So if it's possible ?

Comment: Yes, once you set the password for the user, the access using the network works.

Comment: Does that answer your question or do you need more info? I'm currently doing the whole thing for production, so if you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Hi @toydarian :)

Okay, I found this solution : https://gist.github.com/zak39/a1b342eb8568fcc68728a5a91d92445a 

I'm sorry, my comment it's too long. So, I wrote in comment in my gist one element what I don't understand in the deployment ^^'

Comment: Please keep the discussion here, so people who will find your question later will understand it and be able to solve their problem. You write something about an error, is this still about this question? If yes, please edit your question and add the error message. If it is something new, please ask a new question. You can comment the link to that follow-up question under your initial question, I'll gladly pick it up. In general be as precise when you post on SO, one question per post is a golden rule here ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanation so it also answers the question you posted on github.

Comment: Oooh ! I'm sorry, I don't know the golden rule here x)

Comment: No worries. Did you get all you need from my updated answer?

Comment: Okay so in the SO we can edit our question to add a new content ?

Because I found one Ansible task that can answer to my question but I got an error ><

If I should create a new question, I should copy the URL on this question or there is a button in my question to follow-up ?

I will wait your answer before to edit it :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Are you comment in my gist on github ? Or Are you update one comment here ?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your question to add additional relevant content (often people ask you to add some information). What you should not do is to ask a completely new question by editing an existing one. It depends, on what you want to ask. If you realized that your question needs more info to be understood/answered properly, add it. If it is a new question, just start a new post (you can include a link to the previous one, if it is relevant). I updated my answer here, the one we are commenting on, it is a lot longer now... ;)

Comment: Oooh okay thanks for your answer :)

I am editing my question to add additionnal relevant content :)

Comment: I answered that already, you need to set the root password before adding users. Add the section `Set password for root user` from my answer and include the password before trying to add users.

Comment: Okay I understand. But, it's work whithout to send the `root_cnf.j2` template. So, it's really necessary to send the jinja template ?

Comment: You only need this if you do not have `login_username` and `login_password`. It is not a good idea to have those hardcoded as they provide full access to the server. Additionally, I like to have the config there, because I can just run `mysql` on the server and get directly dropped into a root shell on the database, which is nice, I think.

Comment: @Zak are all your questions answered now?

Comment: Hi @toydarian :)
I'm for yesterday, I worked on another task.
I answer you on your last comment : I think to have understand ! :) This code is in a tutorial progressive. So those login username and password will not be hardcoded :)

I think my problem is resolve ! I will edit my question to put the good code. Should I click on button to mark its fix ? :)

Comment: Do NOT change your question! The question is meant to be and stay a question and the answer is in the answer ;) Please click the check-mark (accept the answer). If you like, you can also upvote my answer, would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Okay no problem to edit my question :)
I will upvote your answer ! :)

Thank you very much ! :)

Just, one thing. How do you think of my english ? :)

Comment: Thanks! Your English is fine. It is clear that you are not a native speaker, but it is very understandable. Btw. you can't upvote yet, you need 15 reputation first... my bad :D But thanks for accepting! :)

Comment: Ahah I am not trust in me in english and I don't know where I use this langage. May be here, in stack overflow, when I have a question on a problem ^^'